# Flask static_folder not found

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

Can you please advise how to fix error 404.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2020 10:00:21] "GET /static/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2020 10:04:32] "GET /static/esp_logo/klaviyo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

On my routes.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, request, abort
site_blueprint = Blueprint('site_blueprint', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')

@site_blueprint.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html', title = "Select ESP")
```

Then on templates >> layout.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">
```

When the flask runs - it returns:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/main.css">
```

My folder structure is: 
[image]

The main.css and the images within folder 'esp_logo' - returns 404.

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/blueprints/#static-files should answer that

Comment: perfect. thank you